# Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")?

Tags: xcode

**Info.plist** contained **no UIScene configuration dictionary** (looking for configuration named **"(no name)"**)?

Upgraded Xcode 14.1 -> 14.2 and got this **brand new error**.

[image: Console Error]

In my **Project** editor, selected **Target** on left and then "**Build Settings**" on top.

[image: Build Settings]

Here's what the Finder shows:

[image]

Tried this Key 1st:

[image: 1st Key]

Error does not go away.

Then this 2nd Key:

[image: 2nd Key]

Error still there.

What simple something am I missing?

Thanks bunches.

**EDIT**

I have my info.plist.file in the same Folder as my .xcodeproj file and indications on my end indicate that this the correct location So, it appears that my error is in the content of my .plist File.

I initially set the key = UISceneConfigurationDictionaryName with content Type = String.

Of particular note is the (no name) value.

Then I set the key = UISceneConfigurationDictionary with content Type = Dictionary.

Same Error.

Puzzling to me is that the drop-down list of Keys does not contain any "UIScene".

Can't prove it, but I believe that this void in the drop-down list is at the heart of my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6245

Answer (score 163, accepted):

I just experienced the same issue and found the fix, at least, for me:

I added the `UISceneConfigurations` key (inside the `UIApplicationSceneManifest` dictionary) and its value as an empty dictionary, like this:

```
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict/>
    </dict>
```

Note, if your app does not support multiple scenes (i.e. multiple windows or screens), then this is sufficient (and may avoid a strange black screen!):

```
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict/>
    </dict>
```

[image]

It compiled and ran successfully without the warning in the debug console, and also automatically removed this key from the `project.pbxproj` file:

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and would like to use this same solution, but I'm not experienced enough to follow the instructions. How do I edit the UIApplicationSceneManifest dictionary? I see something called "Application Scene Manifest (Generation)" under "Info.plist Values" in the Build Settings tab of Xcode, but I can't see anything quite like your screenshot.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I explicitly edited (auto-generated) `Info.plist` location in "Project > Build Settings > Packaging > Info.plist File". Another option is to downgrade to Xcode 14.1 (https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.1/Xcode_14.1.xip)

Comment: @CuriousJorge The "Application Scene Manifest" node in the screenshot about is located under "Info > Custom iOS Target Properties" (a tab _before_ the Build Settings tab)

Comment: @agurtovoy, thanks! Interestingly, I don't have Custom iOS Target Properties, but have a Custom Mac Target Properties. I think it's because my project was made as a "Multiplatform App". The Custom Mac Target Properties don't have the Application Scene Manifest option, so I guess this solution won't work for me.

Comment: With both suggestions, I get a black screen :(

Comment: For XcodeGen you want to add the following key if your Info.plist is auto-generated: `INFOPLIST_KEY_UIApplicationSceneManifest_Generation: false`

Comment: @agurtovoy  Thanks 
  "Project > Build Settings > Packaging > GENERATE Info.plist File" to YES

Comment: Second Option worked for me, thanks!

Comment: First time I got a blackscreen. Second time the app just closes with the following error: `Unexpectedly received animationDidStop without a matching animationDidStart. Monitoring for idle animations may no longer function correctly.`

Answer (score 49):

I was helped by adding the item "Scene Configuration" on the tab "Info" in the project settings.

Just push this button and select "Scene Configuration" from the list:
[image]
After that, Output is clean:
[image]

Comment: i was missing the whole Application Manifest Section...i added this, and when i set the "Enable Multiple Windows" option to yes, my app launches just black...so changed "Enable Multiple WIndows" to NO, and the app starts just fine, and the warning was gone (y)

Comment: This solution is simple and straightforward. Resolved it for me in fewer clicks and less key downs

Comment: This is perfect answer and simple, that's worked for me,thanks.

Comment: This is simple and straight forward answer. I kept "Enable Multiple Windows" value to NO as it was showing blank screen for me.

Comment: given my project has been in progress since 2018, why is it that with nearly every release of Xcode I seem to have to fix a project setting that should have some sort of sensible default if not present!! I don't like Xcode in the first place so this really doesn't help.

Comment: I think its an example of Apple forcing the upgrade cycle, at least for iOS Devs.

Answer (score 11):

I've had the same issue when I updated my Xcode to 14.2, the info.plist file was inside a folder i had created, but finally it worked for me when i put the info.plist file back to the root folder, idk if its necessary but I cleaned the folder after that.

After this, just to keep the organization the way I wanted, I placed the info.plist file inside the folder that I wanted before, but changed the file location in Project -> Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File > fix the file path

adding edits here as i don't have enough reputation to answer/comment:
If the issue is still there, try restarting the machine as that fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

- First add "Application Scene Manifest" to the Info.plist file and just leave the other sub options under it as follows.

[image]

- Then make sure you have added the Storyboard file names for Launch Screen and Main screen properly as follows. (Make sure you the spellings are correct according to your project.)

[image]

- After that, make sure you have removed the code snippet related to Scene Manifest from your AppDelegate file. Should be something along the lines as follows.

[image]

- Finally make sure you have added the following line to the AppDelegate file.

  `var window: UIWindow?`

Now, build and run your app. Should be working fine now.