# When I run in the application simulator the build succeeds but the output is black. this type of error are face

Tags: ios, swift

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd8Ko.jpg)]
When I run it in the application simulator the build succeeds but the output is black. this type of error is faced. The problem is mentioned in this image url.

Comment: Maybe your  storyboard not connected properly in the info plist

Comment: How to know that the storyboard is connected or not? Where to change in the Info.plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        To add a code to the configurationforconnecting function in the app delegate file.
```

Before add code in function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.

}
```

add code in function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    let config = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    config.delegateClass = SceneDelegate.self
    config.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return config
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The error in the screenshot shows that the `UIScene` file is not properly set in your `Info.plist` file. Set it to the you `UIScene` file or remove the key if you are not using a `UIScene`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard your info.plist should have the key like in the image and your storyboard should be named as in the key **Storyboard Name** which is in this case called **Main** and in your SceneDelegate file the function scene(_:willconnect:) should be like in the second image[image: image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: I have checked out both file Info.plist (Image one) and SceneDelegate files (Image two) as per your comment. but still, I face a black screen in the simulator.

Comment: @KrunalKathiriya can you share your root viewController code and are you using constraints programmatically or you are using constraints inside storyboard ? Was your app running properly then this issue happened or this is your first time running the app ?

Comment: Yes, I use constraints inside the storyboard. And the application was running perfectly when this issue occurred. This issue has come in the first time.

Comment: that's good, i can't help you without seeing the code but here is an advice checkout to a new branch then try to revert commit by commit until the issue is fixed and try to trace which line of code caused this issue

Comment: How do I send you the code? because of a lot of lines of code.

Comment: you can create a public github repository and add the code you want to share there and share the link in your question but make sure not to share anything sensitive

Comment: https://github.com/KrunalKathiriya/iOS-issue/issues/2 This is my root view controller screen code

Comment: share the storyboard as well

Comment: https://github.com/KrunalKathiriya/iOS-issue/issues/3 This is my pod file image link
https://github.com/KrunalKathiriya/iOS-issue/issues/4 This is storyboard image link(onboarding VC and navigation controller)

Comment: i assume this issue happened after you  added FSPagerView? also share the onboardingVC constraints on story board to see if any constraints are missing and try to remove  the FSPagerView and see if the problem is fixed

Comment: No error from fpagerview. I have made it for a month. If there is an error, why was the project running fine until now? This error came after I was troubleshooting Firebase. Then after I updated the pod and all these problems occurred.

Comment: i rechecked your attached image and found this error [info.plist contained no uiscene configuration dictionary ]  check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74805019/info-plist-contained-no-uiscene-configuration-dictionary-looking-for-configurat  and  click on the project -> choose info tap and check this key in the info tap Application Scene Manifest not in the info.plist file in your folders sometimes xcode don't sync those correctly

Comment: Still, there are getting a black screen

Comment: have you tried to restart you device sometimes it works like that? if the restart does not fix anything  i see that  you have only one option check every commit in your git and see what changed and what may cause that problem and good luck i see it's a very frustration issue

Comment: I have faced another issue please help me sir https://stackoverflow.com/q/75720637/21312220